Writing to SQLite database using Dapper doesn't work
My code executes without errors, but nothing gets written to the database, and I'm a bit at a loss as to why. Reading works fine (from the table in question) so the connectionString is definitely correct.
public class SqliteCrud(string connectionString)
{
    private readonly string _connectionString = connectionString;
    private readonly SqliteDataAccess _db = new();
    
    public void SaveLastCall(string lastCall)
    {
        var sql = "insert into RequestLog (LastCall) values (@LastCall)";

        _db.SaveData(sql, new { LastCall = lastCall }, _connectionString);        
    }
}

public class SqliteDataAccess() : IDataAccess
{
    public List<T> LoadData<T, U>(string sqlStatement, U parameters, string connectionString)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        var rows = connection.Query<T>(sqlStatement, parameters).ToList();
        return rows;
    }

    public void SaveData<T>(string sqlStatement, T parameters, string connectionString)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Execute(sqlStatement, parameters);
    }
}

Here's a screenshot of my database structure.


Try setting a variable for Execute to see what is returned, should be 1. Also, is the database part of the project? If so check the property Copy to output directory, make sure its not set to copy always.

A very common problem with file-based databases is looking at the wrong file, i.e. every time you build and deploy your app, it can be talking to a different (folder-specific) file. I think this is also what @KarenPayne is alluding to. For example, try reading the row immediately after inserting it, inside your application, using similar methods (your List etc) - if that finds the row, but you aren't seeing it in your database admin tool: you're almost certainly looking at different copies of the same file


Please don't post screen shots.  Post the text.  2.  Can you post your connection-string (app.config or appSettings.json) ?     Hint.  (piggy backing on marc.g comment above).. try a FULL ABSOLUTE path to the filename while you debug.


@MarcGravell I eventually worked it out myself. I was indeed looking at the wrong copy.
